# ADO.NET data model generate from database is leaving out one of my tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am trying to add a ADO.NET to my asp.net project.

It generates everything correctly, except it leaves out one of my tables,

I have a feeling it might be due to a naming issue or something,

It add my one tables called `Users` but then the table it is excluding is called 'UserCompany`how ever I have tried turning off the option to`pluralize or singulise generated object names` and it still does the same,

The UserCompany Table is a simple table consisting of two ints,

Userid , CompanyId

Is there a an issue or a common bug that I am not aware of? ANd how cna I work aroudn this, as I have been using the model successfully up until now where I need to use the one table which aint there.

Comment: where are you adding these tables and where is the information coming from. please supply some source code

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Comment: from a sql server located on the network.  And no it does not have a primary key.

Comment: the bugs I have experience with EF were related to temp table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue,

My one table did not have a primary key, And as far as I know EF requires that your table have a primary key.